# Does exist deadlocks with Tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, task, deadlock

I have the below code and certainly I have a deadlock using Threads, but why not happens with tasks?

```
private static object lockObject1 = new object();
private static object lockObject2 = new object();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Deadlocks";

    //Using tasks.

    Task ourTask1 = new Task(SingleMethod_A);
    ourTask1.Start();

    Task ourTask2 = new Task(SingleMethod_B);
    ourTask2.Start();

    //Using threads.

    //Thread ourThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SingleMethod_A));
    //Thread ourThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SingleMethod_B));

    //ourThread1.Start();
    //ourThread2.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Deadlock");
}

public static void SingleMethod_A()
{
    lock (lockObject1)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        lock (lockObject2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not possible.");
        }
    }
}

public static void SingleMethod_B()
{
    lock (lockObject2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 

        lock (lockObject1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not possible.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `Console.ReadLine();` after the `Console.WriteLine("Deadlock");`

Comment: Hi theodor, good that. The main function can ends before the tasks, i did it but its the same result, no deadlock.

Comment: Try configuring the threads with `{ IsBackground = true }`. The only difference between using threads and tasks in your example is that the threads are foreground, and prevent your program from terminating.

Comment: Threads are ok... my point was with tasks.

Comment: If you add the `{ IsBackground = true }` then the threads will probably stop being OK, and this may help you understand why tasks are also not OK.

Answer (score 1):

`Task`s can certainly dead lock. It is also important to keep in mind that `Task`s aren't threads - they may run on one from the thread pool.

Why you aren't seeing it is because your case is a trivial example and `.Start` doesn't have to use separate threads. Try changing your calls to start to `Task.Run(action)` instead to see the deadlock:

```
Task.Run(() => SingleMethod_A());
Task.Run(() => SingleMethod_B());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Daniel! I did but it's the same result :(

Comment: Based on that simple code, how can be possible to cause a deadlock with tasks?

Comment: @Vmax the main would fall thru so you'd have to do `await Task.WhenAll(...)`

Comment: its hard to come up with a concrete example but it is possible @v